# DeviceIoControl Invalid access to memory location

Tags: c++, winapi, deviceiocontrol, reparsepoint

I am getting invalid access to memory location when I run the following code

```
WIN32_FIND_DATAW FD;
WCHAR cPath[MAX_PATH], cFindPath[MAX_PATH];

if (!GetCurrentDirectoryW(MAX_PATH, cPath))
    ErrorExit("GetCurrentDirectory");
else
    printf("Current Path: %s\n", cPath);

StringCchCopyW(cFindPath, MAX_PATH, cPath);
StringCchCatW(cFindPath, MAX_PATH, L"\\*");

BOOL bsuccess;

HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW(cFindPath, &FD);

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFind)
{
    vector<wstring> links;
    do
    {
        WCHAR  fullFileName[MAX_PATH];
        StringCchPrintfW(fullFileName, MAX_PATH, L"\\\\?\\%s\\%s", cPath, FD.cFileName);

        DWORD dwBufSize = MAXIMUM_REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE;
        REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER* rdata;
        rdata = (REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER*)malloc(dwBufSize);

        DWORD bytesReturned;
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(fullFileName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT | FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);
        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFile)
        {
            if (DeviceIoControl(hFile, FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT, NULL, 0, &rdata, dwBufSize, &bytesReturned, NULL))
            {
                if (IsReparseTagMicrosoft(rdata->ReparseTag))
                {

                    if (rdata->ReparseTag == IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK)
                    {
                        printf("Symbolic-Link\n");
                        size_t slen = rdata->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR);
                        WCHAR *szSubName = new WCHAR[slen + 1];
                        wcsncpy_s(szSubName, slen + 1, &rdata->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PathBuffer[rdata->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameOffset / sizeof(WCHAR)], slen);
                        szSubName[slen] = 0;
                        printf("SubstitutionName (len: %d): '%S'\n", rdata->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameLength, szSubName);
                        delete[] szSubName;

                        size_t plen = rdata->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PrintNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR);
                        WCHAR *szPrintName = new WCHAR[plen + 1];
                        wcsncpy_s(szPrintName, plen + 1, &rdata->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PathBuffer[rdata->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PrintNameOffset / sizeof(WCHAR)], plen);
                        szPrintName[plen] = 0;
                        printf("PrintName (len: %d): '%S'\n", rdata->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PrintNameLength, szPrintName);
                        delete[] szPrintName;
                    }
                    else if (rdata->ReparseTag == IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT)
                    {
                        printf("Mount-Point\n");
                        size_t slen = rdata->MountPointReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR);
                        WCHAR *szSubName = new WCHAR[slen + 1];
                        wcsncpy_s(szSubName, slen + 1, &rdata->MountPointReparseBuffer.PathBuffer[rdata->MountPointReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameOffset / sizeof(WCHAR)], slen);
                        szSubName[slen] = 0;
                        printf("SubstitutionName (len: %d): '%S'\n", rdata->MountPointReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameLength, szSubName);
                        delete[] szSubName;

                        size_t plen = rdata->MountPointReparseBuffer.PrintNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR);
                        WCHAR *szPrintName = new WCHAR[plen + 1];
                        wcsncpy_s(szPrintName, plen + 1, &rdata->MountPointReparseBuffer.PathBuffer[rdata->MountPointReparseBuffer.PrintNameOffset / sizeof(WCHAR)], plen);
                        szPrintName[plen] = 0;
                        printf("PrintName (len: %d): '%S'\n", rdata->MountPointReparseBuffer.PrintNameLength, szPrintName);
                        delete[] szPrintName;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("No Mount-Point or Symblic-Link...\n");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Not a Microsoft-reparse point - could not query data!\n");
                }
                free(rdata);
            }
            else
                ErrorExit("DeviceIoControl");
        }

        CloseHandle(hFile);


    } while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &FD));
}
else
    ErrorExit("FindFirstFile");
```

but the following code works fine.

```
HANDLE hFile;
LPCTSTR szMyFile = ("C:\\Documents and Settings");  // Mount-Point (JUNCTION)
//LPCTSTR szMyFile = _T("C:\\Users\\All Users");  // Symbolic-Link (SYMLINKD)

hFile = CreateFile(szMyFile, FILE_READ_EA, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, NULL);
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf(("Could not open dir '%s'; error: %d\n"), szMyFile, GetLastError());
    return;
}

// Allocate the reparse data structure
DWORD dwBufSize = MAXIMUM_REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE;
REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER* rdata;
rdata = (REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER*)malloc(dwBufSize);

// Query the reparse data
DWORD dwRetLen;
BOOL bRet = DeviceIoControl(hFile, FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT, NULL, 0, rdata, dwBufSize, &dwRetLen, NULL);
if (bRet == FALSE)
{
    printf(("DeviceIoControl failed with error: %d\n"), GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return;
}
CloseHandle(hFile);

if (IsReparseTagMicrosoft(rdata->ReparseTag))
{
    if (rdata->ReparseTag == IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK)
    {
        printf("Symbolic-Link\n");
        size_t slen = rdata->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR);
        WCHAR *szSubName = new WCHAR[slen + 1];
        wcsncpy_s(szSubName, slen + 1, &rdata->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PathBuffer[rdata->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameOffset / sizeof(WCHAR)], slen);
        szSubName[slen] = 0;
        printf("SubstitutionName (len: %d): '%S'\n", rdata->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameLength, szSubName);
        delete[] szSubName;

        size_t plen = rdata->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PrintNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR);
        WCHAR *szPrintName = new WCHAR[plen + 1];
        wcsncpy_s(szPrintName, plen + 1, &rdata->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PathBuffer[rdata->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PrintNameOffset / sizeof(WCHAR)], plen);
        szPrintName[plen] = 0;
        printf("PrintName (len: %d): '%S'\n", rdata->SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PrintNameLength, szPrintName);
        delete[] szPrintName;
    }
    else if (rdata->ReparseTag == IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT)
    {
        printf("Mount-Point\n");
        size_t slen = rdata->MountPointReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR);
        WCHAR *szSubName = new WCHAR[slen + 1];
        wcsncpy_s(szSubName, slen + 1, &rdata->MountPointReparseBuffer.PathBuffer[rdata->MountPointReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameOffset / sizeof(WCHAR)], slen);
        szSubName[slen] = 0;
        printf("SubstitutionName (len: %d): '%S'\n", rdata->MountPointReparseBuffer.SubstituteNameLength, szSubName);
        delete[] szSubName;

        size_t plen = rdata->MountPointReparseBuffer.PrintNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR);
        WCHAR *szPrintName = new WCHAR[plen + 1];
        wcsncpy_s(szPrintName, plen + 1, &rdata->MountPointReparseBuffer.PathBuffer[rdata->MountPointReparseBuffer.PrintNameOffset / sizeof(WCHAR)], plen);
        szPrintName[plen] = 0;
        printf("PrintName (len: %d): '%S'\n", rdata->MountPointReparseBuffer.PrintNameLength, szPrintName);
        delete[] szPrintName;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No Mount-Point or Symblic-Link...\n");
    }
}
else
{
    printf(("Not a Microsoft-reparse point - could not query data!\n"));
}
free(rdata);
```

I am trying to get the reparse data for the files in a given folder. This is my `REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER`

```
typedef struct _REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER {
ULONG  ReparseTag;
USHORT  ReparseDataLength;
USHORT  Reserved;
union {
    struct {
        USHORT  SubstituteNameOffset;
        USHORT  SubstituteNameLength;
        USHORT  PrintNameOffset;
        USHORT  PrintNameLength;
        ULONG   Flags; // it seems that the docu is missing this entry (at least 2008-03-07)
        WCHAR  PathBuffer[1];
    } SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer;
    struct {
        USHORT  SubstituteNameOffset;
        USHORT  SubstituteNameLength;
        USHORT  PrintNameOffset;
        USHORT  PrintNameLength;
        WCHAR  PathBuffer[1];
    } MountPointReparseBuffer;
    struct {
        UCHAR  DataBuffer[1];
    } GenericReparseBuffer;
};
} REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER, *PREPARSE_DATA_BUFFER;
```

I Dont know where I went wrong. Please help me fix my first code.

Comment: are so hard say at which concrete line you got invalid access to memory ? you not try run your code under debugger first, more wrote more info about error ?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue (which you didn't explain in enough detail anyway), `"C:\\Documents and Settings"` is a bug waiting to happen. This certainly won't run on a localized version of Windows, or any recent (NT based) version of Windows. See [Known Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776911.aspx) for solutions.

Comment: in which portion does invalid access to memory happens. have you check the **GetLastError** code

Comment: @Angelica: When code triggers an access violation, `GetLastError` will not return anything useful.

Comment: @IInspectable - the second code snippet obvious is *test code* on OP system only, but not release code. in this kind of *test code* absolute normal *hardcode* any concrete paths for test

Comment: http://blog.kalmbach-software.de/2008/02/28/howto-correctly-read-reparse-data-in-vista/ ,code executes when fixed path is specified.  problem would be in folder enumeration logic plus other errors as stated by @RbMm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your code containing 2 errors how minimum

you unconditionally call `FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT` for all files, but you must do this only

```
if (FD.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT) {..}
```

otherwise you got `ERROR_NOT_A_REPARSE_POINT` in `DeviceIoControl` and then `ErrorExit("DeviceIoControl");` executed.

and second error at this line:

```
DeviceIoControl(hFile, FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT, NULL, 0, &rdata, dwBufSize, &bytesReturned, NULL)
```

`&rdata` - !!

when must be

```
DeviceIoControl(hFile, FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT, NULL, 0, rdata, dwBufSize, &bytesReturned, NULL)
```